# Reading from multiple JTextFields into array

Tags: java, arrays, jtextfield, shortest-path

I'm working on shortest path alghoritm, and wanted to create a gui version for my program. This is my method creating fields to input distances between vertices. When all JTextFields are filled I want to convert all of it into two dimensional array and here is my problem. How to read all values from n amount of JTextFields if they're all created on the same variable which is *tekst* in my case.

```
void Wypelnij() {
int n = 1;
int x = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= wierzcholki; i++) {

    if (x == 0) {
        mojPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
        for (int j = 1; j <= wierzcholki; j++) {
            if (n == wierzcholki) {
                mojPanel.add(new JLabel("" + j), "wrap");
                n = 1;
                x = 1;
            } else {
                mojPanel.add(new JLabel("" + j));
                n++;
            }
        }
    }
    mojPanel.add(new JLabel("" + i));
    for (int j = 1; j <= wierzcholki; j++) {
        JTextField tekst = new JTextField();
        tekst.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
        if (n == wierzcholki) {
            mojPanel.add(tekst, "wrap");
            n = 1;
        } else {
            mojPanel.add(tekst);
            n++;

        }
        if (i == j) {
            tekst.setText("0");
            tekst.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            tekst.setEditable(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `List<JTextField>` and iterate over that list to get text from all the `JTextFields`.

Other way is, you can use [`Components[] JPanel#getComponents()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29) to get all components of panel(*i.e.* Container) and iterate over the components to read from the `JTextFields`. But in this case your panel may contain other components(*better to use separate panel for `JTextFields`*) and moreover you need to cast `Component` to `JTextField`. But, you can iterate over `Components[]` based on the *indexes* on which you have added `JTextFields` in your panel.